# Deploy Django on Heroku with Docker heroku.yml

Tags: django, docker, heroku

I'm using Docker locally for Django development and trying to use Heroku to [deploy with Docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml). But I'm getting complains about "no web processes running" aka no Dynos spun up. So missing this config somehow but find no mention of it on Heroku or the few tutorials out there.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

`heroku.yml`

```
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: heroku-postgresql
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

I suspect the issue is in the `run` section of `heroku.yml` but pretty stuck.

Comment: Side note, you shouldn't be using `manage.py runserver` in production. Install a WSGI server (`gunicorn` would be a popular choice) and use that instead. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. Somehow when running `heroku stack:set container` instead the  `heroku-18` stack was used, which also automatically runs `collectstatic`. So that was the issue.